# How can I make a variable out of an ID that is made after the item using the ID is created?

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir

The problem I am having is in my testing I create an order which obtains an ID. This ID is different every-time.

Here is a picture of some sample code:
[image]

Thanks in advance to any help.

--Curtis

Comment: What is the problem? What *do* you know about the element?

Comment: To make it clearer. What string *exactly* from this page would you like to put in a variable? How would a regular user distinguish this link from other links on the page?

Comment: The part that is selected in blue contains a number. This number is new every time an order is created. Also when inspecting the element it show up as shown above. So what I did was grabbed the whole line of text as suggested in the answer below and gsub out the before and after while placing it into a new variable to be received later on in the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell exactly by the code provided, but wouldn't something this simple work

`testID = @browser.div(:class, /screenlet-title-bar/).text`

followed by some string manipulation to trim any unnecessary space or characters:

`testID.gsub(" Purchase Order #", "") #Removes leading text`

Comment: So the first line of code you gave me worked great. But, the second line of code does not remove the leading text.

Comment: I played around with it for awhile and got the .gsub to work the way I need it to. Thanks for leading me in the right path :)

Comment: Np - glad you were able to figure it out. You do need to be careful to track the text in that div during development to make sure that you're still editing the text that you think you are ;).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried XPath? [Here is a tutorial](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/XPath) on it.

```
testID = @b.link(:xpath, "//a[contains(@href, '/ordermgr/control/orderview?orderID')]/").text
```

The output should be the ID you need. If you have multiple ID's with the same xpath, it could be a problem, didn't try that.

Good Luck,

Dave

Comment: I still have not been able to make this xpath thing find the link of text I am looking for. Is there something I need to install besides watir (firewatir) and ruby?

Comment: No, you should have everything that you need. I tried this out before I posted it and it worked for me. Can you post your code and error? I guess you have tried more than one, so the one you think should work.